# Accessing Journey Data (Salesforce Activity output) in Email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder

In JB I've used Object Activity to create a SF object. This activity produce a SF object ID as output, I can use this output in other shapes using:

```
{{Interaction.SALESCLOUDACTIVITY-1.salesforceObjectID}}
```

I would like to use this journey data variable in Email AMPScript but it seems not documented.
Can someone tell me what the correct way would be access the related data in my Emails?
Thank you!